# Using Alter Statement from a Table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have a table like  having  one column containing this data

| Dummy Column |
| --- |
| Alter PACKAGE ABC COMPILE; |
| Alter PACKAGE CDE COMPILE; |
| Alter PROCEDURE ABC COMPILE; |
| Alter TRIGGER ABC COMPILE; |

I want to make a script such that when i run that it will execute the alter statements line by line and perform the DDL operations.

Comment: Check out ```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE```

Comment: I tried execute immediate but how can i use for each row?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve compiling the objects one by one ? Have a look at ```dbms_utility.compile_schema``` which compiles all objects for you.

Comment: I was not aware of  dbms_utility.compile_schema. It solved my problem easily.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work, obviously assuming you have real DDL statements stored in that dummy column.

- `for` `loop` over the column when the value is not null
- replace the `;` by nothing in order to use `execute immediate`

Example

```
declare
vsql table.dummy_column%type;
begin
   for h in ( select dummy_column from table where dummy_column is not null )
   loop
       vsql := replace(h.dummy_column,';','');
       execute immediate vsql;
   end loop;
end;
/
```